# Best practice for displaying Firebase many-to-many relationships in the view (AngularFire)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire, nosql

I have found a lot of examples on how to structure many-to-many relationships in Firebase. Following the most recommended way I've seen to set it up I have some basic posts and tags data in Firebase:

```
/posts:
  -K_GOdSQvCQ2sAcHfo1x
    - descpripton: "This is a post..."
    - title: "This is a title..."
    - tags:
       -K_aBTTDKVUovZe3l0lX: true
       .....
  -K_GFDQjPoSmCJM3YAlB:
    - description: "Another post..."
    - title: "This title..."
    - tags:
        -K_aBTTKDhYsnbFv1Tuc: true
        ......

/tags:
      -K_aBTTDKVUovZe3l0lX
        - name: "Sport"
        - postIds:
           -K_GOdSQvCQ2sAcHfo1x: true
           .....

      -K_aBTTKDhYsnbFv1Tuc:
       - name: "Movies"
       - postIds: 
          -K_GFDQjPoSmCJM3YAlB: true
          .....
```

My problem is figuring out how to handle these relationships in my views. I haven't been able to find any tutorials or examples covering it.For example, in the index view I wish to list all posts with their respective tags attached.

So far I've been simply returning all posts and all tags and storing them in separate `$scope` variables. That's fine but I haven't been able to figure out how to display only the tags relative to each post. I first thought it should be possible trying a nested `ng-repeat` structure. But it's proving trickier than I expected to get this working.

This is the idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
<!-- For each tag in post object iterate tags --> 
<div data-ng-repeat="t in posts.tags">
    <span data-ng-repeat="tag in tags">
      <!-- display only tags here that match with post.tag.id -->
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm thinking that it is perhaps possible using Angular's `filter` in conjunction with `ng-repeat` but I've had no luck finding any examples to work from. Maybe what I am trying to do is not possible in the view alone or too cumbersome/ugly. If anyone can give me some pointers on how I might approach it that would be great!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I have found a way to achieve this but I'm sure it's not optimal. If anyone can inform me on a better approach I'd be grateful.

For example, in the code below I feel that using `<h5 ng-if="key === post.$id">` isn't the right way to match the `posts` to the `tags`. Maybe there is a standard way of using the boolean values to do this? I'm still a bit new to Firebase/AngularFire so I am eager to learn any emerging design patterns for solving this problem.

Again, the goal is pretty standard. The `posts` and `tags` are coming from separate Firebase nodes that have a many-to-many relationship(allowing posts to have many tags and tags to belong to many posts).

In the controller for the index view all posts and all tags are retrieved and saved separately to their own `$scope` variables. The following view code is how I managed to display the relevant tags inside each post preview.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="post in posts">
    ........
    <div ng-repeat="tag in tags">     // Iterate tags      
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tag.postIds"> // Iterate postIds in each tag
        // Check tag.postId key against the current post id. 
       //  Should be using booleans some way here instead?? 
         <h5 ng-if="key === post.$id"> 
           <span class="label label-default">
              {{tag.name}}
           </span>
         </h5>
      </div>
    </div> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: denormalize your data.

A bit longer answer: You need to save the data in a way that helps you be efficient when you query it. So for this particular case, you could save the tag's name instead of just `true` which only shows association.

So instead of

```
{
  posts:
    -K_GOdSQvCQ2sAcHfo1x: {
      descpripton: "This is a post...",
      title: "This is a title...",
      tags: {
        -K_aBTTDKVUovZe3l0lX: true
      }
    }
}
```

You could save it like

```
{
  posts:
    -K_GOdSQvCQ2sAcHfo1x: {
      descpripton: "This is a post...",
      title: "This is a title...",
      tags: {
        -K_aBTTDKVUovZe3l0lX: "Sport" // <----- Notice the change
      }
    }
}
```

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) (and others, like [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)) videos from the official Firebase chanel. Extremely helpful.